# Datetime on blade laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

How to get **month name** on blade laravel ?

i tried this but the result is the month number

```
$training->date_activity->month
```

Answer (score 0):

as per the documentation of Carbon, your approach is correct. 
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters

Yet it could be the property is not considered a Carbon DateTime. 
Can you make sure that in the Training Model you have 'date_activity' as a date mutator?

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'date_activity'
];
```